# subfigure in llncs class

Tags: subfloats

When I am using `\usepackage{subfigure}` with `\documentclass{report}` it is working fine and I am able to use it but if I use `\usepackage{subfigure}` with `\documentclass{llncs}` then the file is not compiled and gave me output as 0 error ... 0 Page(s) with Couldn't file input index file file_name and file_name.idx

Can someone help me what should I do? I want to display two figures side by side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

package `subfigure` is obsolete, use `subfig` instead. You can also try package `floatrow`. You'll get the documentation with running `texdoc subfig` or `texdoc floatrow`